# How do I cache a personalised fragment in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

My app (Rails 4) allows users to vote on posts. Is it possible to cache the post, but personalise the vote cache so it shows one personalised for current_user? For example, whether the user voted or not.

I would rather not change the html structure to achieve this.

```
# posts/_post.html.slim
- cache post do
  h1 = post.title
  = post.text
  = render 'votes/form', post: post

# votes/_form.html.slim
- if signed_in? && current_user.voted?(post)
  = form_for current_user.votes.find_by(post: post), method: :delete do |f|
    = f.submit
- else
  = form_for Vote.new do |f|
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options here:

## Option 1: don't cache the votes

This is the simplest solution and the one i personally recommends. You just don't cache the dynamic user dependent part so you have something like this:

```
# posts/_post.html.slim
- cache post do
  h1 = post.title
  = post.text
= render 'votes/form', post: post # not cached
```

## Option 2: use javascript

This solution is more complex, but is actually how basecamp do it (however mostly with more simple examples).  You have both part rendered on the page but remove one of them with javascript. Here is a example using jQuery and CoffeeScript:

```
# posts/_post.html.slim
- cache post do
  h1 = post.title
  = post.text
  = render 'votes/form', post: post

# votes/_form.html.slim
div#votes{"data-id" => post.id}
  .not_voted
    = form_for current_user.votes.find_by(post: post), method: :delete do |f|
      = f.submit
  .voted
    = form_for Vote.new do |f|
      = f.submit

# css
.not_voted {
  display:none;
}

# javascript (coffeescript)
jQuery ->
  if $('#votes').length
    $.getScript('/posts/current/' + $('#votes').data('id'))

# posts_controller.b
def current
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

# users/current.js.erb
<% signed_in? && current_user.voted?(@post) %>
  $('.voted').hide();
  $('.not_voted').show();
<% end %>
```

I would however properly change `voted?` method to accept a id, so you don't need to make a new query. You can learn more about this approach in this railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/169-dynamic-page-caching-revised?view=asciicast

Comment: Thanks. How does changing voted to receive an id prevents it from doing an extra query? Isn't it already available as an instance variable? The only query you need is `votes.where user_id = foo and post_id = foo`.

Comment: Yes but with the javascript solution will `$.getScript` trigger a ajax request that then would set the `@post` instance variable through a db query. If you could just have a `@post_id` would this be faster which is important in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you. One last comment. Your first solution means I can't render a collection, as in `= render @posts` because rendering the vote will happen from within the `_post` partial, and it will be cached. I would need to loop over the collection, cache and render each post individually, then outside of the cache block render the `_vote` partial. Right?

Comment: Right but you could solve that problem by touching (call `touch` or adding `:touch => true` on the association between the vote and the post) on the post when a user votes on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, this will create 2 different fragments for both voted and not voted for each post. It will be read by according to its status.

```
# posts/_post.html.slim
- cache [post, current_user.votes.find_by(post: post)]do
  h1 = post.title
  = post.text
  = render 'votes/form', post: post
```